# Account Confirmation with MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble setting up account validation with an ASP.NET MVC website.

I have followed several tutorials, but I cannot get it working in my application.  The generated code that comes in the email looks something like this:

http://localhost:32939/confirm/14/Pgwmt6CTw3Mev/AuzYmGOjqQBK3ZUEz6ncRV67rB3FSsrRwKJJKezRRymlnfMmUglHcPuDXvgtJ6JB7nCEWlojIflU7OyOscEd6afx7slWlycTyW6KbMOeqO0CWzpPPycOXnr4qpqffUZQ5BCq86Lw%3d%3d

Everything after the confirm/ is the code.  I am using attribute based routing - could that be the cause of the issue?

Here is how I implement it:

```
private OperationResult SendConfirmation(Profile Item)
{
    try
    {
        string Callback = Url.Action("Confirm", "SpaceHome", new { Area = "Space", ID = Item.Profile.Id, Code = Code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        string EmailBody = String.Format("<p>Thank you for signing up for our site.</p><p>Please use the following link to confirm your account.</p><a class='btn btn-blue' href=\"{0}\">Confirm Account</a>", Callback);

        Q.Users.SendEmail(Item.User.Id, "Account Confirmation", EmailBody);

        return OperationResult.Success();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return OperationResult.Failure(ex);
    }
}
```

The Email arrives as would be expected.  Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet, Route("confirm/{ID:int}/{Code}"), AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Confirm(int ID, string Code)
{
    OperationResult Result = new OperationResult(Q.Users.ConfirmEmail(ID, Code));
    return View();
}
```

When I enter the generated URL into a browser, the Controller is never activated.  Instead, I receive a 404 error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled attribute routing in your routing config?

Comment: You url also has 3 values `14`, `Pgwmt6CTw3Mev` and `AuzYmGOjqQ......` but you route definition only has 2.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I assume the / is part of the code, not another segment

Comment: @luke2012 - Yes, I use attribute routing throughout my application and it is enabled.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - yes, the / is part of the automatically generated code - it seems odd that they would use that character...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code contains a / character, which is causing your route to not be selected.

Unfortunately, Attribute routing doesn't seem to support catch-all slugs, like the standard MVC routing does.  So you may have to define a standard route with a catch-all slug (ie {*code})

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Confirm",
    url: "confirm/{ID}/{*Code}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Confirm" });
```

Comment: I am working on verifying this now - out of curiosity, do you know why the generated code includes all of these non-ascii characters that add complexity to routing?  Couldn't I just create a random string of numbers and digits?

Comment: @William - All of those characters are ASCII characters, i'm not sure why you think they aren't.  How are numbers different from digits?

Comment: sorry - I didn't mean ASCII - I meant letters and numbers (A-Z and 0-9).  When I generate the code using ASP.NET Identity it uses slashes and pluses which is making me have to handle the routing differently in this one circumstance - my question is whether I can make it so that the Confirm code only uses letters and numbers.